# How are these codes related to each other?

Tags: c++, reference

I am reading Scott Meyers' [article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) on universal references, and I don't quite get this part:

> A third reference-collapsing context is typedef formation and use. Given this class template,
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> class Widget {
>      typedef T& LvalueRefType;
>      ...
> };
> ```
>
> and this use of the template,
>
> ```
> Widget<int&> w;
> ```
>
> the instantiated class would contain this (invalid) typedef:
>
> ```
> typedef int& & LvalueRefType;
> ```
>
> Reference-collapsing reduces it to this legitimate code:
>
> ```
> typedef int& LvalueRefType;
> ```

Type `int` is being used, but the template is for type `Widget`.  How are the codes related to each other?  TIA.

Comment: Could you post a clear question please ? What exactly is related to each other and what's not to understand ?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to explain what you think is obvious. For example, you unequivocally state that type `int` being used, but I don't see that. (Type `int&` is being used, but not `int` by itself.) Perhaps you could start by explaining your current understanding?

Comment: The `Widget` class template is shown.  Then `the instantiated class` is said to contain something.  I would like to know where this `int&` and class come from.

Answer (score 0):

That part of the article assumes a bit of familiarity with templates. If you're not familiar with template terminology, it might be better to learn templates before trying to understand that "reference-collapsing context". Or maybe a brief run-down would be adequate. I'll err on the side of explaining things.

> ```
> template<typename T>
> class Widget {
>      typedef T& LvalueRefType;
>      ...
> };
> ```

This is a [class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template). It is a blueprint for defining classes, without actually defining one. Before using this blueprint, a type must be specified for use within the blueprint (represented by `T` in this example).

> ```
> Widget<int&> w;
> ```

This defines a variable (`w`) whose class is generated using the blueprint. Remember that the blueprint requires a type to be specified? This example specifies `int&` as that type. Why `int&`? **shrug** It's the type Scott Meyers wants to use. Authors get to decide arbitrary things like that. Don't worry about it.

So what happens when you specify a type? The blueprint is copied, and substitutions are made in the copy. In this case, each instance of `T` is replaced by `int&`, giving a specific class definition. This class definition is called an instantiated class named `Widget<int&>`. You won't see this definition anywhere; it's something the compiler works out. However, if you're willing to be a bit lax with valid C++ syntax, the following suggests what the class definition would look like:

```
class Widget<int&> {
     typedef int& & LvalueRefType;
     ...
};
```

In the `typedef` line, the `T` from the template was replaced by `int&`. I also added a space after it to separate it from the ampersand that follows it (`T&` and `T &` mean the same thing). This brings us to the next line of code from the article:

> ```
> typedef int& & LvalueRefType;
> ```

Look familiar? The whole point of the setup was to get this weird-looking code that appears to make use of a reference to a reference (to an `int`). Now we get to reference-collapsing. You cannot take a reference to a reference, yet the language authors did not want to automatically invalidate this sort of template use. So there's a clause somewhere in the language specification that says that in this sort of situation, the compiler should adjust the instantiated class by getting rid of one of the ampersands in the troublesome line.

When you remove an ampersand from the line we're dealing with, you get the final line of code you quoted. This is effectively what the compiler will use when it generates the definition of `Widget<int&>`.

> ```
> typedef int& LvalueRefType;
> ```

So that's a rather quick and incomplete look at templates, with just enough detail to (hopefully) make sense of that part of the article.